# Swift Errors: whereKey and NSArrays

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Creating an iOS app with Swift. I've run into the following errors that I can't seem to get around. Help appreciated.

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: HonkHonkTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! HonkHonkTableViewCell

    let honkHonk: PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject

    cell.honkTextView.text = honkHonk.objectForKey("content") as! String

    var dataFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd MM:mm"
    cell.timeStampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(honkHonk.createdAt!)

    var findUser: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    findUser.whereKey(key: "objectId", equalTo: honkHonk.objectForKey("user")!.objectId)

    findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let user: PFUser = (objects as! NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Errors:

- Cannot invoke whereKey
- Cast from AnyObject to NSArray always fails

Comment: Did you try `objects?.last` instead of casting into `NSArray`? Also, I guess Swift 2 compiler will ask you to change `findUser` from `var` to `let`.